# Typecasting error while loading folders and sub folders with librosa

Tags: python, numpy, audio, librosa, spectrogram

I am having some trouble to visualize mel-spectrogram for WAV files contained inside folders and sub folders for deep learning using librosa..

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from glob import glob
import librosa as lr
import librosa.display
import IPython.display as ipd

pathAudio = 'Sounds'
files = librosa.util.find_files(pathAudio, ext=['WAV'])
files = np.array(files, dtype=float)
sr = 22050

for y in files:


    ipd.Audio(files, rate=22050)
    scale, sr = lr.load(files)
    filter_banks = lr.filters.mel(n_fft=2048, sr=22050, n_mels=10)
    filter_banks.shape
    plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
    librosa.display.specshow(filter_banks,
                             sr=sr,
                             x_axis="linear")
    plt.colorbar(format="%+2.f")
    plt.show()
    mel_spectrogram = lr.feature.melspectrogram(scale, sr=sr, n_fft=2048, hop_length=512, n_mels=10)

    mel_spectrogram.shape

    log_mel_spectrogram = lr.power_to_db(mel_spectrogram)
    log_mel_spectrogram.shape

    plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
    librosa.display.specshow(log_mel_spectrogram,
                             x_axis="time",
                             y_axis="mel",
                             sr=sr)
    plt.colorbar(format="%+2.f")
    plt.show()
```

Here,I am getting an error message:

```
files = np.array(files,dtype=float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

I tried visualizing spectrogram for a single WAV file and didn't get any errors..

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import IPython.display as ipd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scale_file = "audio/scale.wav"

ipd.Audio(scale_file)

# load audio files with librosa
scale, sr = librosa.load(scale_file)

filter_banks = librosa.filters.mel(n_fft=2048, sr=22050, n_mels=10)

filter_banks.shape

plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
librosa.display.specshow(filter_banks, 
                         sr=sr, 
                         x_axis="linear")
plt.colorbar(format="%+2.f")
plt.show()

mel_spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(scale, sr=sr, n_fft=2048, hop_length=512, n_mels=10)

mel_spectrogram.shape

log_mel_spectrogram = librosa.power_to_db(mel_spectrogram)

log_mel_spectrogram.shape

plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
librosa.display.specshow(log_mel_spectrogram, 
                         x_axis="time",
                         y_axis="mel", 
                         sr=sr)
plt.colorbar(format="%+2.f")
plt.show()
```

but when I tried making mel-spectrograms for large number of wavefiles inside folders and sub folders..i got error!!
It would be a huge help if anyone could find a way to fix this issue...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

To start, replace

```
files = np.array(files, dtype=float)
[...]
ipd.Audio(files, rate=22050)
scale, sr = lr.load(files)
```

with

```
files = np.asarray(files)
[...]
ipd.Audio(y, rate=22050)
scale, sr = lr.load(y)
```

There may be more issued after that.

This other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62383417/942774) may also help.